# Create a simple UserControl

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-store

i'm trying to create a simple Windows Store App.
I want to reuse some "code" in many pages.

For example i need to reuse someting like this in more than one page..

```
<StackPanel> 
   <TextBlock Text="Name"/>
   <TextBox x:Name="edtNome"/>
```

Maybe the best method is using "UserControl"...but i can't realize how!

i've created mine MyUC.xaml

```
<UserControl
x:Class="Crud.View.MyUC"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Crud.View"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid>
   <StackPanel>
       <TextBlock Text="Name"/>
       <TextBox x:Name="edtName"/>
   </StackPanel>
```

But now?
I want to put it in my Page.xaml (and in many other), and access the "edtName" from page.xaml code behind.....

what i have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

in xaml use a binding path. Add an x:Name for your control. ElementName=me 'me' will be the name given to your control

```
<TextBox x:Name="edtName" Text="{Binding Path=EditName, ElementName=me, Mode=Default}" ..../>
```

in that code behind add

```
public string EditName
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(EditNameTextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(EditNameTextProperty, value); }
}

 public static readonly DependencyProperty EditNameTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("EditName",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(YourClassNameHereForThisControl),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(""));
```

Comment: ok, this just for my MyUC.xaml and MyUC.xaml.cs, now i want to include it in another page

Comment: sorry but i can't understand. How i can use it in another page? What i have to do to use it in page1.xaml? What i have to write in page1.xaml? how can i access to edtName from page1.xaml.cs?

Comment: You need to reference it in your XAML by adding another xmlns:UC="...." IntelliSense should help you fill it out. Points to the namespace of your UserControl. 'UC' can be any name you want to reference your control. Then you add it into your pages XAML like <US.MyClassName .... />

Comment: done... but doesn't work, but i can only read using `myuc.FindName("edtName") as a TextBox`.... maybe i must fix something in my MyUC... `<TextBox x:Name="edtName" Text="{Binding Path=EditName, ElementName=me, Mode=TwoWay}"`   what exactly i have to set instead of  `new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(""))` in the code behind

Comment: Can you post your XAML and code behind as it is now.

Comment: which ones? the "page1" or the usercontol? the second it's copied by yours,`public static readonly DependencyProperty EditNameTextProperty =
               DependencyProperty.Register("EditName",
                   typeof(string),
                   typeof(MyUC),
                   new PropertyMetadata(" "))`  and `<TextBox x:Name="edtName" Text="{Binding Path=EditName,ElementName=me, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

Comment: See my update. I forgot to tell you that ElementName=me, the me needs to be a name you give to the control with x:Name.